# SetInterval and input fields

Tags: javascript

Ok i have two input fields with keyup event, this is js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        is_draft_started = 0;

        $(":input").keyup(function() {
            if(is_draft_started == 0) {
                s2 = setInterval('draft("' + frm_name + '")', auto_save_time);
                is_draft_started = 1;
            }
        });
```

setInterval call function draft

```
var frm_name = 'myform';
    var auto_save_time = 1000 * <?php echo AUTO_SAVE_TIME?>;

    <?php if($_GET["uid"] != "" && isset($_GET["uid"])): ?>
            var id_draft = '<?php echo $draft->id?>';
    <?php else: ?>
            var id_draft = 0;
    <?php endif; ?>

    function draft(forma_name) {
        if(id_draft == 0) {
            $.post("?c=licnePoruke&f=slanje&pk=<?php echo $pk?>&saveDraft=1", $("[name=" + forma_name + "]").serialize(), 
                    function(data) {
                        id_draft = data;
                                                $('#draft_id').val(id_draft);
                        last_save_time();
                    }); 
        }
        else {
            $.post("?c=licnePoruke&f=slanje&pk=<?php echo $pk?>&updateDraft=" + id_draft, $("[name=" + forma_name + "]").serialize(), 
                    function(data) {
                        last_save_time();
                    });
        }

        return false;
    }
```

but somehow in draft function first if is called twice, a cant figure why. Any help for my problem

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, where the later function execute the callback(like `draft`) every time you meet the auto_save_time, like 1000ms, 2000ms, 3000ms.......